# Gets FormatException when trying to query data to Parse.com in Unity

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine, formatexception

I'm using Parse plugin 1.5.5 for Unity 5.1.3 in order to communicate with Parse.com in Unity. I'm getting **FormatException** when trying to connect to Parse when there is no internet connection with following code. I was wondering if this is a bug of Parse plugin or anything I did wrong.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Data");
query.FirstAsync().ContinueWith (task =>
{
    if (task.IsCanceled)
    {
        Debug.Log ("parse canceled");
    }
    else if(task.IsFaulted)
    {
        Debug.Log ("parse error");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log ("parse retrieved");
    }
});
```

Error code is following.

```
FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format
System.Int32.Parse (System.String s) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-   runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Int32.cs:629)
Parse.PlatformHooks+HttpRequestUnity.getStatusCode (UnityEngine.WWW www)
Parse.PlatformHooks+HttpRequestUnity+<>c__DisplayClass40+<>c__DisplayClass46.<ExecuteAsync>b__3a (UnityEngine.WWW www)
Parse.PlatformHooks+<>c__DisplayClass24.<RegisterNetworkRequest>b__23 ()
Parse.PlatformHooks+<RunDispatcher>d__2e.MoveNext ()
UnityEngine.Debug:LogException(Exception)
Parse.<RunDispatcher>d__2e:MoveNext()
```

Thank you,

Comment: I'm having the same problem... found this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/894167517342133/?search_id did you create it?